# поиск повторяющихся слов из файла

Tags: java, arraylist, java-hashmap

Сразу скажу сейчас еще изучаю Java и мне дали задачу. Суть задачи есть файл с данными о городах(айди, название, регион, население, первое упоминание), нужно вывести в консоль название региона и количество городов которые в нём есть( например Москва - 10). Оптимальным решением было посчитать не сумму городов, а количество повторений названия региона. данные о городах из файла заполнены в ArrayList.Изначально я перевёл List в массив, потом массив в hashMap и заполнил его названием городов и регионов и вывести этот список не проблема, а как посчитать так и не могу понять:(

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<City> cityList = ReadFile.parse();
    City cityArray[] = cityList.toArray(new City[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < cityArray.length; ++i);
    Map<String, String> regionAndCity = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0;i < cityArray.length; i++)
        regionAndCity.put(cityArray[i].getName(), cityArray[i].getRegion());
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> s : regionAndCity.entrySet())
        System.out.println(s.getValue() + " " + s.getKey());
}
```

}

Comment: содержимое самого файла прикрепите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну и код какой-то недописанный: в нём циклы, в которых ничего не происходит, структуры данных, в которых нет данных. Кода, реализующего основную функцию поиска и подсчёта нет совсем. Надо сначала с этим разобраться, а потом уже выяснять, почему алгоритм не работает.

Comment: код подправил, просто после кучи перебора, кое что не так написал и получились циклы без смысла, в файле 1083 строки такого формата:
"16;Белогорск;Амурская область;Дальневосточный;68220;1860" и вот из этого всего мне нужно как то сделать так что бы посчитать сколько раз упоминается каждый регион

Comment: Есть мысль что перед 
 System.out.println(s.getValue() + " " + s.getKey());
прописать условие сравнения и уже потом в консоль, но как правильно написать понять не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все слишком сложно. Бессмысленные циклы, бессмысленное созданием массива с городами из коллекции... Задача решается в одну строку кода (я вынес эту самую строку в отдельный метод). При этом считать можете по любому полю, за это отвечает второй параметр метода и сейчас это регион:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<City> cityList = ReadFile.parse();
    Map<String, Long> result = count(cityList, City::getRegion);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static Map<String, Long> count(List<City>cities, Function<City, String> identity) {
    return cities.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(identity, Collectors.counting()));
}
```